# How to justify the inequality $\int_0^{|s|} x^{N-1} e^x dx\le e^{|s|} \int_0^{|s|} x^{N-1} dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality

I am trying to justify the inequality
$$\int_0^{|s|} x^{N-1} e^x dx\le e^{|s|} \int_0^{|s|} x^{N-1} dx.$$

Following what idea was this done?

I was thinking it might come out of integration by parts, but doing computations I see that it is not the case.

Could someone please help to justify that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's increasing, so bounded by its value at the right end point?

Comment: On the integration range $e^x \leq e^{|s|}$, it's just that